# Enabling Multiple tagging to single Resource group with multiple policy Deny Action

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-policy

definition 1:

```
"if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "tags['Project Identifier']",
        "match": "..."
      }
```

definition 2:

```
"if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "tags['Date']",
        "match": "##-##-####"
      }
```

the effect for both definitions is **deny**, I'm unable to apply both the policies to a single resource group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just merge them to a single policy file, something like this:

```
"if": {
    "AnyOf": [
        your_rule_1,
        your_rule_2
    ]
}
```

This would deny resource unless both rules do not match

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#logical-operators